# Multiple OK/Cancel dialogs, how to tell, in onClick(), which dialog?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I created a generic OkCancelDialog class that is conveniently invoked throughout my app via a static method:

```
  static public void Prompt(String title, String message) {
    OkCancelDialog okcancelDialog = new OkCancelDialog();
    okcancelDialog.showAlert(title, message);     
  }
```

For various reasons I need the onClick listener in the activity, so in the activity I have:

```
  public void onClick(DialogInterface v, int buttonId) {
    if (buttonId == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) { // OK button
         // do the OK thing
    }
    else if (buttonId == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) { // CANCEL button
         // do the Cancel thing
    }
    else {
      // should never happen
    }
  }
```

This works great with a single dialog in the app, but now I want to add another OK/Cancel dialog, handled by the same activity. As far as I can tell, only one `onClick()` can be defined for the activity, so I am not sure how to go about implementing this.

Any suggestions or tips?

Comment: are you going to have multiple dialogs on the screen at once?

Comment: @Tim No. Only one dialog at a time. It looks like `DialogInterface v` is a clue but I don't really know how to use it to accomplish this tricky thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
    implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    // Declare dialogs as Activity members
    AlertDialog dialogX = null;
    AlertDialog dialogY = null;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        if (dialogX != null) {
            if (dialogX.equals(dialog)) {
                // Process result for dialogX
            }
        }

        if (dialogY != null) {
            if (dialogY.equals(dialog)) {
                // Process result for dialogY
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** This is how I create my `AlertDialogs`...

```
private void createGuideViewChooserDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select Guide View")
        .setSingleChoiceItems(guideViewChooserDialogItems, currentGuideView, this)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", this)
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", this);
    guideViewChooserDialog = builder.create();
    guideViewChooserDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Almost working. `dialogX.equals(dialog)` returns false for some reason because `AlertDialog` is not the same as `DialogInterface`. How do I resolve this? And casting produces **ClassCastException**. +1 I'm almost there...

Comment: I'm a little confused as the code I posted in my answer is pretty much a copy/paste from working code of my own. `AlertDialog` implements `DialogInterface` which should mean it would work (and as I said it works for me).

Comment: Mine implements `DialogInterface` too, and if I don't cast I don't get ClassCastException but `dialogX.equals(dialog)` still returns **false**. Are you sure that `equals()` works for `implements`?

Comment: I've triple-checked my code to try and work out how this isn't working for you. Perhaps it's how you create your dialogs. I've edited my answer to show how I build a dialog to allow a user to switch from a view of a TV Guide. In this case in my original code example this would be `dialogX`. I have another `AlertDialog` handled by the same `onClick` listener and it processes them without problems using the `equals(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices. 1) You can set the OnClickListener on the dialog itself. 2) You can tell which dialog is which based on the DialogInterface that's passed in.